# How to add legend with specific values and frame

Tags: plotting, legending, frame

I need to add well-defined ticks in this range **Ticks -> {Range[0, Pi, Pi/6], Automatic}** to the following plot

[image]

This is the code but it is incomplete. Comments and suggestion to solve it

```
Plot[{  1/2 (1 + Cos[x]^2), Sin[x]^2/(1 + Cos[x]^2) , 
  1/2 (1 + Cos[x]^2) BesselJ[0, Sin[Pi/3] x]^2, 
  Sin[x]^2/(1 + Cos[x]^2) BesselJ[0, Sin[Pi/3] x]^2}, {x, 0, Pi}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, Pi, Pi/6], Automatic},  PlotLegends -> Placed[{Subscript[(Subscript[\[Sigma], s]), PW],  Subscript[\[CapitalPi], PW](\[Theta]), Subscript[(Subscript[\[Sigma], s]), BB], 
    Subscript[\[CapitalPi], BB](\[Theta])}, {0.86, 0.5}]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the options `Frame` and `FrameTicks` in `Plot` and the option `LegendFunction -> Framed` in `LineLegend`:

```
Plot[{1/2 (1 + Cos[x]^2), Sin[x]^2/(1 + Cos[x]^2), 
  1/2 (1 + Cos[x]^2) BesselJ[0, Sin[Pi/3] x]^2, 
  Sin[x]^2/(1 + Cos[x]^2) BesselJ[0, Sin[Pi/3] x]^2}, {x, 0, Pi},
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Range[0, Pi, Pi/6], Automatic}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Subscript[(Subscript[σ, s]), PW], 
     TraditionalForm@Subscript[Π, PW][θ], Subscript[(Subscript[σ, s]), BB], 
     TraditionalForm@Subscript[Π, BB][θ]}, LegendFunction -> Framed], {0.86, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Use `LegendFunction -> "Frame"` to get

[image]